# Enthought Canopy Pandas not installing

Tags: pandas, enthought

Using Enthought Canopy; the following command `import pandas` produces this error message:

```
ImportError: C extension: hashtable not built. If you want to import pandas 
from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --
inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Which I understand means that the package hasn't been built with it's C dependencies? I thought Canopy's environment handled module installations, I have tried removing, and updating `Pandas` with no luck.

Does anyone know how to correctly use `Pandas` in Enthought Canopy?

Comment: Pandas should be installed by default with Canopy. Does running `enpkg pandas --forceall` from a Canopy Terminal/Command Prompt (accessible from the Tools menu) allow you to `import pandas` in Canopy? If not, please submit a bug report through Canopy's help menu.

Comment: Updating the Canopy Environment appears to have done the trick - thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You are quite welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forcing a reinstallation of Pandas and its dependencies with `enpkg pandas --forceall` run from a Canopy Terminal/Command Prompt seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: It actually only seemed to work after reinstalling Canopy entirely.

Comment: Very interesting. Something else to check for if this happens again is an "easy-install.pth" file in your User site-packages. This can get created if you run `setup.py develop` and the presence of "easy-install.pth" will incorrectly modify `sys.path` to point to the Canop's Core environment site-packages before User. Deleting "easy-install.pth" can rectify the issue. See: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/400

Comment: Ok thanks, I will keep this in mind if I come across the problem again.